# Atlassian Bamboo Unable to publish artifact

Tags: angular, build, bamboo, artifact

I have a simple build plan for an Angular project. Basically, just:

- Source Code Checkout
- npm clean cache
- install packages
- ng build for prod

What I'm building is development instead of master and this build plan suppose to supply artifacts for a deployment project. Currently, I'm getting error as below, any help which be appreciated and I can provide more information as needed.

`20-Jan-2021 17:41:51   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\fsevents): 20-Jan-2021 17:41:51    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) 20-Jan-2021 17:41:51    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\rollup\node_modules\fsevents): 20-Jan-2021 17:41:51    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) 20-Jan-2021 17:41:51    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents): 20-Jan-2021 17:41:51    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) 20-Jan-2021 17:41:51     20-Jan-2021 17:41:51    removed 1 package and audited 1857 packages in 16.914s 20-Jan-2021 17:41:51    found 932 vulnerabilities (897 low, 1 moderate, 34 high) 20-Jan-2021 17:41:51      run` npm audit fix`to fix them, or`npm audit `for details 20-Jan-2021 17:41:52     20-Jan-2021 17:41:52    > jira@0.0.0 ng C:\Bamboo Agent\xml-data\build-dir\JFE-JFEDB0-JOB1\loc-development 20-Jan-2021 17:41:52    > ng "build" "--prod" 20-Jan-2021 17:41:52     20-Jan-2021 17:43:13     20-Jan-2021 17:43:13    chunk {} runtime.7d7e9038a1cdbceb3d53.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered] 20-Jan-2021 17:43:13    chunk {1} main.76f75a6c8d5ec15169cd.js (main) 2.45 MB [initial] [rendered] 20-Jan-2021 17:43:13    chunk {2} polyfills.0f3595340ee54eabdb76.js (polyfills) 45 kB [initial] [rendered] 20-Jan-2021 17:43:13    chunk {3} polyfills-es5.06a04082366fd96b93a4.js (polyfills-es5) 128 kB [initial] [rendered] 20-Jan-2021 17:43:13    chunk {4} styles.ea56f7b9720562d8d3ea.css (styles) 490 kB [initial] [rendered] 20-Jan-2021 17:43:13    Date: 2021-01-20T06:43:13.283Z - Hash: 792cf95f2875def59fbd - Time: 64687ms 20-Jan-2021 17:43:13     20-Jan-2021 17:43:13     20-Jan-2021 17:43:13    Unable to publish artifact [Jira Frontend Web Dev]:  20-Jan-2021 17:43:13    The artifact is required, build will now fail.`

Answer (score 0):

What happened was because it's a branch off master, it ends up in a sub directory. What I had to do was specify the sub directory (branch name) for Location in the artifact definition.